# Ошибка при запущеном SSH Agent: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, armbian-linux

При выполнении

```
ssh-agent -s
```

Пишет PID ssh-agent'a, но при попытке сделать ssh-add получаю ошибку:

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`

При этом `ps ax | grep ssh` видно что `ssh-agent`  запущен, корректно отрабатывает только когда запускаю так: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` в чем разница?

Хочу сделать авто добавление ключей при ребуте таким скриптом:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/right/.ssh/
eval $(/usr/bin/ssh-agent -s)
/usr/bin/ssh-add github_cents
```

Но в итоге ключи не добавляются, а `ssh-agent` запущен

Comment: *ключи не добавляются* — как вы это определили?

Comment: ну конкретно в случае с Git я получаю ошибку: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` при попытке сделать `git pull`

Comment: а указать нужный ключ непосредственно в `/home/right/.ssh/config` нельзя?

Comment: Извиняюсь, но не знал что так можно было сделать

Comment: Правильно запускать агента нужно так: `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`. А вообще это должно быть на системном уровне в скриптах в */etc*. Сейчас никто руками агентов не запускает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения конкретно для данного случая не нашел. Альтернатива подходящая в моем случае - помещение в ~/.ssh/config конфигурации для нужного хоста:

```
Host server.com
  IdentityFile ~/keys/.ssh/id_dsa
```